# not getting markers on map from corresponding longitude latitude values fetched from MySql

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to plot longitude latitude values from MySql on google map with marker. Code for fetching longitude latitude value is correct as code displays those values while using Toast Message. The problem is that everything goes fine except I can't see any markers on google map. Here is my source code.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private String JSON_STRING;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    getJSON();



   /* LatLng sydney = new LatLng(33, 88);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
*/
}


private void showLongLat(){
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;

    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_JSON_ARRAY);

        for(int i = 0; i<result.length(); i++){
            JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
            String id = jo.getString(Config.TAG_ID);
            String longitude = jo.getString(Config.TAG_LONG);
            String latitude = jo.getString(Config.TAG_LAT);
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),latitude+longitude,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

           LatLng marker = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(longitude),Double.parseDouble(latitude));

            //LatLng sydney = new LatLng(42+i,87-i);

            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marker).title("Marker Somewhere"));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(marker));

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}




private void getJSON(){
    class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{

        ProgressDialog loading;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(MapsActivity.this,"Fetching Data","Wait...",false,false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            JSON_STRING = s;
            showLongLat();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            String s = rh.sendGetRequest(Config.URL_GET_ALL);
            return s;
        }
    }
    GetJSON gj = new GetJSON();
    gj.execute();
}


}
```

Comment: can you please show in what format are your coordinates? it is important to have big precision in order to add marker

Comment: My coordinates are in string format and I've converted them into Double.

Comment: I mean give me sample coordinates which stored in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the values of latitude and longitude. This line:

```
LatLng marker = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(longitude),Double.parseDouble(latitude));
```

Must be:

```
LatLng marker = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitude),Double.parseDouble(longitude));
```

Comment: thanks dude... I'd also noticed it after posting question over here ;)